# Bootstrap Navigation - Collapse and move nav (button) to the bottom (navbar-fixed-bottom)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm building simple navbar with a logo and a single button. I want the button to collapse on smaller screens and move to the bottom with a fixed navbar. Similar to https://onlycoin.com/

I'm not quite sure how to do this and I could use any suggestions/help.

This is the code that I am using for the navbar:

```
    <!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="60" data-offset-bottom="200">
  <div class="container">

      <div class="logo">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Nano-Ojas™</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">  
          <li>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-btn btn btn-danger">Order Now</button>
          </li>
        </ul>               
    </div>
  </div>
</nav> 


<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom visible-xs-inline-block">
    <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">  
              <li>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-btn btn btn-danger">Order Now</button>
              </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div><!-- Navigation -->
```

Comment: I only modified the nesting, did not delete any of your code. You seem to be missing a closing div for your container.

Comment: They just repeated the button and stuck it in a fixed position div that shows at that breakpoint. Use the bootstrap responsive utility class visible-xs and then put your fixed positioning on the wrapper

Comment: Thank you very much @Christina. It worked. Can I continue to pick your brain? How would I center the button/nav using visibility-XS?

Comment: if you want to center it use .visible-xs-inline-block and then apply "text-align:center" to the parent.

Comment: @Christina   Is this correct? I added the "visible-xs-inline-block" however the button is not center justified. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have no idea how your html structure is. If you add text-align:center to the parent of the button, it will center.

Comment: @user3769502 hey never change the code of your question. if you solved it, then write it as an answer and explain what you did. or add as an edit.

Comment: Will do - sorry I'm new to Stackoverflow.